Representation of a meromorphic function on a once-punctured complex plane in terms of its zeros and poles
Consider a meromorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ such that both $0$ and $\infty$ are its essential singularities with finite order in the sense of value distribution theory (see for example part VIII of T. Shimizu, "On the theory of meromorphic functions", Japan J. Math. 6(1929) 119-171, JFM 55.0197.01, for the definition of order of an isolated essential singularity).
Could we use the value distribution theory to give a representation for $f$ of the Weierstrass-Hadamard type in terms of its zeros and poles?
As you know, if $f$ is meromorphic at $z=0$, then such a representation exists almost uniquely (Theorem 1.9. in W. K. Hayman, Meromorphic Functions, Oxford University Press, 1964, MR164038, Zbl 0115.06203). Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much for editing my question! Your changes have made it much clearer and more precise. I really appreciate your help! @Daniele Tampieri

Bin Xu, you are welcome.  I'm glad of having been of some help.

It is a product of two meromorphic functions:
$$f(z)=g(z)h(z),$$
where $g$ is meromorphic in $C$ and $g$ is meromorphic in $\overline{C}\backslash\{0\}$, so that $h(z)=h_1(1/z)$ where
$h_1$ is meromorphic in $C$. To prove this split the zeros and poles into two subsets, one in $|z|<1$ another in $|z|\geq1$, and construct Weierstrass' products for these subsets. If your $f$ is of finite order, these products can be chosen to be of finite genus.
Factoring these products out, you obtain a function without zeros or poles in $C^*$. Each such function has the form
$$z^me^{P(z)},$$
where $P$ is entire, and $m$ is an integer. If your original $f$ is of finite order, then the usual argument shows that $P$ is a Laurent polynomial.
This representation is almost unique (in the same sense as the representation of a function meromorphic in $C$). The integer $m$ has the following geometric interpretation: it is the winding number of the image of the circle $|z|=r$
under the zero-and-pole-free factor.

Thank you very much for your helpful response. I have a few additional questions regarding the second paragraph of your answer. I believe that your Laurent polynomial $P$ should be of the form $ P_1(z) + P_2\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$, where both $ P_1 $ and $P_2$ are polynomials. Am I correct in this assumption? Furthermore, could you kindly elaborate on why such a function must take the form $z^m e^{P(z)}$? Your assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot for your careful explanation.

@Bin Xu:  Yes, this is a definition of Laurent polynomial. Concerning the proof, it repeats the same steps that the proof of the usual Hadamard representation: first you show that for f
of finite order, the zeros-and-poles free factor is also of finite order (both at 0
and at ∞).
), then that the expression under the exp must have at most polynomial growth both at 0
and at ∞.
